# How does spring-security-samples-form-jc login redirect to inbox.jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

How does the login page in sample application [spring-security-samples-form-jc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples/form-jc) in [Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE/) redirect to JSP page `WEB-INF/views/messages/inbox.jsp`?  I see no configuration or source file in the sample that refers to that page.  The sample has just five JSP/HTML pages and only two Java source files, so it doesn't take long to review all of the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project depends [spring-security-samples-messages-jc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples/form-jc/build.gradle#L9) on which includes a MessageController which [resolves the messages/inbox view](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples/messages-jc/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/mvc/MessageController.java#L30).

Comment: Oh, I had not noticed this dependency!